# How to know if a package from Node Package Management (NPM) is tested

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm

I am relatively new to Node.js and NPM, and I have a kind of naive question. I would like to know if there is a way to know if package published on NPM is tested, and if there is away could we automate that process, and if there is tool or framwork that tell me this packages is tested. Also, does NPM require developers to provide a test for their packages.

Thank you

Comment: If package has `npm test` command and files of test frameworks such as karma, protractor, so logically it is tested

Comment: No, NPM doesn't require tests, and you can only know by trying to use `npm test`, looking at the downloaded code if tests are included, or checking the package out on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

NPM is just a package manager. As they say in their site,

> It's a way to reuse code from other developers, and also a way to
>   share your code with them, and it makes it easy to manage the
>   different versions of code.

NPM does not require developers to provide a test for their packages.

Best to use a package that has more stars and downloads cos that vouch for the package.

P.S: Never forget that a [developer can pull his/her code from npm](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/) anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know absolutely for sure, but usually a good indicator is if the author/maintainer has a test script set in the module's `package.json`. npm does not require modules to have tests.

Answer (score 1):

NPM doesn't require package developers to write tests for their code.

**To understand if a specific package is tested**, the best you can do is browse the source code of the package: does it have tests? Just unit tests or other types like integration tests and the like? Are these tests ready to run with straightforward commands? Do these tests offer good code coverage of the package? Do they actually test relevant cases?

**To automate a process that tells you if a package has been tested**, this process will have to make multiple checks within the source code of the package, as there are multiple conventions on how to write, name and structure tests within a Node.js codebase (not to mention the amount of available testing frameworks that can be used). My concern with this approach is how complicated (if possible) would it be to automatically determine if a package is *well tested*, without actually having a human look at the tests.